# jQuery select 7 table cells after

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a calendar booking system and days are divided into 30 minute intervals. When a user hovers over one 30 min section, I would like to automatically highlight the table cell in the row directly under it as well so as to illustrate booking an entire hour. Table is set up as below. Trying to figure out how to select the 7th td after the one I hover. So if i hover over the first td in 6:00am row I will change background for both this cell and the first td in the 6:30am row.

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
                <th>Saturday</th>
                <th>Sunday</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>6:00am</th>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>6:30am</th>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
                <td class="bookLink"></td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('td').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    var index = $('td').index(this);
   $(this).add($('td').eq(index + 7)).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzHW7/)**

```
var $tds = $('.tblHoverTest').find('td'); //get and cache all the tds of the table
$tds.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){ //register event
    var index = $tds.index(this); //get the index of current td with respect to all ts
   $(this).add($tds.eq(index + 7)).toggleClass('active'); //apply class to this td and the 7th td preceeding this using index.
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yBRG6/)**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just needing to highlight the first cell in the following row, you can do so easily with jQuery (I'm just targeting the first cell in each row for this example):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr td:eq(0)').hover(
        // mouseenter event
        function() {
            var $next = $(this).parent('tr').next('tr');
            $(this).add($('td:eq(0)', $next)).addClass('hovered');
        },
        // mouseleave event
        function() {
            var $next = $(this).parent('tr').next('tr');
            $(this).add($('td:eq(0)', $next)).removeClass('hovered');
        }
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qeF74/

Also I've taken the liberty of adjusting your table code, **th** elements should only be used within **thead** and you should never mix them within the same row (the first cell in your example is using a **th**, the following using **td's**). You can then wrap up your repeating rows in a **tbody** tag and just use **td** for all cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery, you can use the [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function, something like:

```
$("td").hover(function() {
    var i = $(this).parent("tr").find("td").index(this);
    var cellToHighlight = $(this).parent("tr").next("tr").find("td").eq(i);
    // do something to highlight it
});
```

That's not super clean code but it's trying to show the idea.